# Composite Components or ui:include?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

Which of those techniques can support **inter-module** ajax updates?

( The content is above 1100 line in a single JSF 2.0(facelets) page. Even if I use one of the above techniques to modularize the page, I need still be able to update one module from another module.)

Which is that technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both can do that. In the `render` attribute you just have to specify the (absolute) client ID of interest. Updates operate fully at the client side based on the client ID. The client side exist of a HTML DOM tree, not being aware at all that it is originally been generated by JSF composite components or include files.